# Get singleValueExtendedProperties

Tags: php, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I'm try to get the singleValueExtendedProperties of my event (I need to get all event with or without singlevalue) PHP code:

```
$queryParams = array(
        '$select' => 'subject,organizer,start,end,singleValueExtendedProperties',
        '$orderby' => 'createdDateTime DESC'
    );
```

but it's not functional.

Comment: Hello, how is it not functional? What output are you expecting and what output are you getting?

Comment: I need to have all information in my select (subject,organizer,start,end) and the singleValueExtendedProperties but the output contain only subject,organizer,start,end not the singleValueExtendedProperties

Comment: You would need an expand statement in there somewhere that specifies the property definitions for the SingleValueExtedendedProperties you want to access https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http